# Связь многие ко многим Code First

Tags: c#, postgresql, mvc, codefirst

Имеется две модели данных, между ними пытаюсь реализовать связь многие ко многим

```
 public class Post
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = ("integer"))]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = ("varchar(250)"))]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        public Post()
        {
            Users = new List<User>();
        }
    }


    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = ("varchar(250)"))]
        public string Login { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = ("varchar(250)"))]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = ("varchar(250)"))]
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            Posts = new List<Post>();
        }
    }
```

При миграции в БД(Postgresql) выскакивает следующая ошибка:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Post.Users' of type 'ICollection<User>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Comment: Вы не указали, по какому ключу вы делаете связь. Поэтому EF ругается и предлагает пометить коллекцию как NotMapped

Comment: @funforlifefix Я так понимаю, нужно присвоить ForeignKey обоим Id, с ссылкой на модели друг друга, но лучше подскажите как это сделать)

Comment: @funforlifefix Сделал как сказал выше, вышла таже  ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить ещё одну сущность которая будет связывать 2 других.
Пример:

```
public class Person
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public ICollection<UserPost> UserPosts { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; key; }
   public ICollection<UserPost> UserPosts { get; set; }
}

public class UserPost
{
   public int UserID { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
   public int PostID { get; set }
   public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Затем в классе вашего `DbContext` в методе `onModelCreating` указать связь:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPost>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.UserID, x.PostID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPost>()
            .HasOne(x => x.User)
            .WithMany(x => x.UserPosts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPost>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Post)
            .WithMany(x => x.UserPosts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PostID);
    }
```

Comment: P.S. Настройка связей в данном методе производится через Fluent API. Здесь же можно настроить ключи сущностей ```User ``` и ```Post ``` вместо указания атрибутов ```[Key] ```

Comment: Я понял, а как теперь при обращении к одной таблице получать сразу данные из второй? Я руководствовался этой статьёй, но у меня так не выходит
https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.8.php

Comment: ```User user = dbContext.User.Where(x => x.iD == userId).FirstOrDefault(); Post = user?.UserPosts?.FirstOrDefault()?.Post; ``` Добавьте ещё нужные условия поиска и проверки на null

Comment: Если не настроены EF proxy добавляйте ```Include ```. ```dbContext.User.Include(x => x.UserPosts).Where(...) ```