# Реализация связи многие ко многим EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework-core

Имеется следующий контекст SCtx:

```
    class SCtx : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        public SCtx()
        {
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=helloappdb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }


    public class User
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            Jobs = new List<Job>();
        }
    }
    public class Job
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        public Job()
        {
            Users = new List<User>();
        }
    }
```

И следующий код:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SCtx DB = new SCtx();
            User User1 = new User 
            { 
                Name = "User1" ,
                Jobs=new List<Job>
                {
                    new Job{Value="Job1"},
                    new Job{Value="job2"},
                }
            };
            User User2 = new User
            {
                Name = "User2",
                Jobs = new List<Job>
                {
                    new Job{Value="Job2"},
                    new Job{Value="job3"},
                }
            };
            DB.AddRange(User1, User2);
            DB.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Получается, что при создании БД я получаю две таблицы : Users и Jobs ,но ко всему прочему таблицу их связей JobUser. Проблема состоит в том ,что полученные таблицы будут выглядеть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть поскольку в каждом классе я добавляю new Job{} , то всегда создается новая строка в таблице.
Как реализовать простой механизм добавления User'a ,чтобы в таблице Jobs не было повторений, а именно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но при этом не хотелось бы расписывать связи ,как тут [Связь многие ко многим Code First](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128708/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bc-code-first) и работы с Fluent API

Comment: Efcore 5, поддерживает mtm из коробки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы добавляете обоим юзерам *разные* задания с одинаковым значением.
Просто создайте это задание отдельно и назначьте его.

```
Job job2 = new Job { Value = "job2" };

User User1 = new User
{
    Name = "User1",
    Jobs = new List<Job>
    {
        new Job{Value="Job1"},
        job2 // <--
    }
};
User User2 = new User
{
    Name = "User2",
    Jobs = new List<Job>
    {
        job2, // <--
        new Job{Value="job3"},
    }
};
```

---

> А если мне допустим на вход уже передали готовый класс User'a ,то как удобнее всего добавить его в БД так , что если данная работа уже есть в БД ,то она не будет повторно создана?

Это нужно решать следующим образом.
Сперва ищем в БД задание с таким же значением. Если нашли - добавляем юзеру именно его. Не нашли - создаём новое задание.

```
string value = "job2";

Job job = DB.Jobs.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Value == value);

if (job == null)
    job = new Job { Value = value };

User user = new User();
user.Jobs.Add(job);
```

Comment: А если мне допустим на вход уже передали готовый класс User'a ,то как удобнее всего добавить его в БД так , что если данная работа уже есть в БД ,то она не будет повторно создана?

Comment: @XupypG - обновил

Comment: Огромное спасибо,не первый раз спасаете